# django radio buttons displayed inside <ul>

Tags: python, django

I dynamically generate my html using the django form template everything works fine except the radio buttons are displayed inside a `<ul><li>` and is not a formatting I like. How can I overwrite this formatting, I just want the radio buttons to be side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to override the template.  Just change the css to format the list how you want (horizontal li).  Here's an example: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change this, without CSS or a custom widget, by using a template to render your form. For instance:

```
{% for radio in myform.beatles %}
<div class="myradio">
    {{ radio }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

will generate the following HTML:

```
<div class="myradio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="beatles" value="john" /> John</label>
</div>
<div class="myradio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="beatles" value="paul" /> Paul</label>
</div>
<div class="myradio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="beatles" value="george" /> George</label>
</div>
<div class="myradio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="beatles" value="ringo" /> Ringo</label>
</div>
```

To get even more granular, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect

Answer (score 1):

Modifying RadioSelect Widget to have custom layout, [here](https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/~bm6432/Django-Modifying+RadioSelect+Widget+to+have+horizontal+buttons) is one way to do this.